# automatically change keyboard shortcuts when keyboard layout changes

Tags: macos, keyboard, language

I have a MacBook Pro with American keyboard, but I also use a Bluetooth keyboard with Spanish layout.
To cycle through windows I use command+` in the built in keyboard, but when I'm using the Spanish keyboard this does not work and I have to change the shortcut to command+º (this is the key that is in the corresponding position  on top of the tab key).
Is there a way to quickly or automatically change this shortcut so I don't have to open the settings window every time when I change the input source?

Comment: BTW If you'd test the _example_ **AppleScript** _code_ in my answer to first see it works for you in general and then determine the `key code` for the **`º`** character, then make the change to the _script_, I can then write up directions for how to automate the _code_ to run when you switch _keyboard layouts_. This is done by use of a **Launch Agent** that watches for changes to the **com.apple.HIToolbox.plist** _file_ and if the _value_ of `AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID` is set to e.g., `com.apple.keylayout.Spanish` the **AppleScript** _code_ is run to handle that scenario.

Comment: There will need to be other modifications to the _code_, which I'll do once I have the missing info, so it changes the _keyboard shortcut_ appropriately when it's switched back to e.g. **English** and the _value_ of `AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID` is set to e.g., `com.apple.keylayout.US`, or whatever the need is. My answer as originally posted it just _proof of concept_ for toggling the target _keyboard shortcut_ but can be easily modified for a fully automated solution once I have the missing info.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Updated Answer**

The purpose of this update is to provide a fully automated solution to the changing of the *keyboard shortcut* used for **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Keyboard** > **Move focus to next window** when the user switches between **English** and **Spanish - ISO** on the **Input** *menu* of the **menu bar** and between the use of the built-in **US English** keyboard and the attached **Bluetooth** keyboard with a **Spanish - ISO** layout.

There was a time when one could use `PlistBuddy` and or `defaults` in **Mac OS X/OS X** to modify an entry in the **com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist** *file* to accomplish this task and it would just automatically update, however, the update is no longer possible in **macOS** without rebooting. As a result, this will be accomplished by using **AppleScript** run by `osascript` as a **Launch Agent** and **UI Scripting** of the *keyboard shortcut* for **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Keyboard** > **Move focus to next window**, while not having to reboot.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, was tested and worked for me without issues as is under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.7 and **macOS Big Sur** 11.2.2 as a *shell script* using a `#!/usr/bin/osascript` *shebang*, and a **Launch Agent** that watches for changes to the **com.apple.HIToolbox.plist** *file* and changes to the *value* of its **AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID** *key*.  It also checks the *value* of *parameters* of the **AppleSymbolicHotKeys** for the target *keyboard shortcut*, (27 in this use case), in the **com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist** *file* to ensure the changes to the **com.apple.HIToolbox.plist** *file* only trigger when changing of the target *keyboard shortcut* because the *keyboard input method* has changed.

The following steps are necessary to implement this solution and once completed, it is fully automatic thereafter, until the **Launch Agent** is *stopped*, *unloaded* and removed when no longer needed/wanted.

---

**Create the *shell script*:**

<sup>Hint: Copy and paste the *shell commands* from here to **Terminal**, and use the same *window* until completely finished.</sup>

In **Terminal**, assuming the `pwd` is your **Home** *directory*:

```bash
touch changeKSforMFTNW; open -e changeKSforMFTNW; chmod +x changeKSforMFTNW
```

Copy and paste the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, shown further below, into the opened **changeKSforMFTNW** *document* and then save and close the *document*.

Back in **Terminal**:

```
[ ! -d '/usr/local/bin/' ] && sudo mkdir /usr/local/bin/ 
sudo mv -v changeKSforMFTNW /usr/local/bin/
sudo -k
```

---

**Create the Launch Agent:**

With the *shell script* taken care of, create the **Launch Agent** in **Terminal**, assuming the `pwd` is your **Home** *directory*:

```
cd Library
[ ! -d 'LaunchAgents' ] && mkdir LaunchAgents
cd LaunchAgents
touch com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
open -e com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
```

Copy and paste the *example* **XML Plist** *code*, shown further below, into the opened **com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist** *document* and **change `you` in the *value*** for **WatchPaths** to your **Home** *directory*, then save and close the *document*.

With the the **com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist** *file* set up and before *loading* it as the **Launch Agent**, `osascript` needs to be added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**. To do this, in **Terminal** run `open /usr/bin`, and in the **Finder** *window* that opens to `/usr/bin` locate the `osascript` *file* so it can be dragged and dropped in the next step.

Open **System Preferences** to **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and click the **Lock**, enter your (Admin) credentials and then drag and drop `osascript` onto the list on the right side of **Accessibility** and ensure it is checked. You can then close **System Preferences**.

**NOTE:** Make sure you do this before loading the **Launch Agent**.

---

**Loading the Launch Agent:**

Back in **Terminal**:

```
launchctl load com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
```

This loads the **Launch Agent** and the first time you select the target language from the **Input** *menu* on the **menu bar** that is not currently selected, if **System Events** under **osascript** **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Automation** is unchecked or not there, a *dialog box*, e.g. '*"osascript" wants access to control "System Events". Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in "System Events" and to perform actions within that app.*', will appear and you need to click the **OK** button.

Note that if you were presented with the aforementioned *dialog box*, the *shell script* will fail this first time because of the *dialog box*, but just select again the target language that is not currently selected from the **Input** *menu* on the **menu bar** and it should work this time.

**NOTE:** Because this is using **UI Scripting**, once you have selected a target from **Input** *menu* on the **menu bar** you will need to allow the **UI Scripting** to complete uninterrupted!

I found in testing that in normal switching between **English** and **Spanish - ISO** on the **Input** *menu* of the **menu bar** that the **UI Scripting** would take place almost immediately and take two or three seconds to complete. Time may vary base on speed of the system, what other process are running and if any are **CPU** intensive at the time.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
#!/usr/bin/osascript

--  # Flush cache on the 'com.apple.HIToolbox.plist' file.
--  # Flush cache on the 'com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist' file.
--  #
--  # The next three lines of code are commented out (with a # character)
--  # and I found them not to be necessary, but have left them in if timing
--  # debugging becomes necessary if the cache does need to be flushed.

# do shell script "defaults read com.apple.HIToolbox.plist 'foobar'; exit 0"
# do shell script "defaults read com.apple.symbolichotkeys 'foobar'; exit 0"
# delay 0.5

--  # Get the fully qualified POSIX pathname of the target .plist file.

set thePropertyListFilePath to POSIX path of ¬
    (path to preferences from user domain) & ¬
    "com.apple.HIToolbox.plist"

--  # See which keyboard layout is the current one.

tell application "System Events" to ¬
    tell property list file thePropertyListFilePath to ¬
        set theCurrentKeyboardLayout to value of ¬
            property list item "AppleCurrentKeyboardLayoutInputSourceID"

--  # Get the value of the parameters of the AppleSymbolicHotKeys for the
--  # target keyboard shortcut as an aggregated numeric string to be used
--  # to stop the script from processing all of its code if the watched .plist
--  # changes for other than to the currently selected keyboard layout.

set shellCMD to ¬
    {"/usr/libexec/PlistBuddy -c ", ¬
        "'Print :AppleSymbolicHotKeys:27:value:parameters' ", ¬
        "$HOME/Library/Preferences/com.apple.symbolichotkeys.plist | ", ¬
        "awk '/[0-9]/{sub(/[ ]+/, \"\"); printf( \"%s\", $0 );}'"} ¬
        as string

set ksNumericValue to do shell script shellCMD

if (ksNumericValue is "96501048576") and ¬
    (theCurrentKeyboardLayout is "com.apple.keylayout.US") then
    return
else if (ksNumericValue is "186101048576") and ¬
    (theCurrentKeyboardLayout is "com.apple.keylayout.Spanish-ISO") then
    return
end if

--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it is actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane.
--  # 
--  # This UI Script needs it to be visible, hence the activate command.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

--  # System Events does the navigating around the 
--  # Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane and changes
--  # the value of the target keyboard shortcut.

tell application "System Events"
    
    --  # Make sure the UI is ready to be navigated.
    
    repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of ¬
        tab group 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "System Preferences")
        delay 0.05
    end repeat
    
    --  # Press the Tab key twice.
    
    repeat 2 times
        key code 48
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    --  # Select 'Keyboard' from the list on the left.
    --  # This is wrapped in a try statement to get
    --  # past a bug in how the select command is 
    --  # interpreted and is silently eaten.
    
    try
        select (every row of ¬
            table 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" whose ¬
            value of static text 1 = "Keyboard")
    end try
    
    --  # Select 'Move focus to next window' from the 
    --  # list on the right. This is wrapped in a try
    --  # statement to get past a bug in how the select  
    --  # command is interpreted and is silently eaten.
    
    try
        select (every row of ¬
            outline 1 of ¬
            scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" whose ¬
            value of static text 1 of ¬
            UI element 2 is "Move focus to next window")
    end try
    
    --  # By default, when System Preferences opens, focus is in
    --  # the Search text box, and depending on whether or not the
    --  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
    --  # is checked, it makes a difference when 'UI Scripting' is
    --  # being used. Set a flag so as to handle the differences.
    
    set isChecked to ¬
        the value of ¬
            checkbox 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" as boolean
    
    --  # Based on the state of the target check box,
    --  # press the Tab key the necessary times to
    --  # navigate to and or open the text field for
    --  # input of the target keyboard shortcut.
    
    if isChecked then
        delay 0.1
        repeat 3 times
            key code 48 --  # Tab key.
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    else
        key code 48 --  # Tab key.
        delay 0.01
    end if
    
    --  # Toggle the value of the target keyboard shortcut.
    
    if theCurrentKeyboardLayout is "com.apple.keylayout.US" then
        key code 50 using command down --   # ⌘` keys
    else if theCurrentKeyboardLayout is "com.apple.keylayout.Spanish-ISO" then
        key code 10 using command down --   # ⌘º keys
    end if
    
    delay 0.5
    
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

<sup>Because of the comments and coding style the *script* is very long. It ends with `tell application "System Preferences" to quit`, so make sure you highlight all of it when copying and pasting to **Script Editor** for testing and or into the ** changeKSforMFTNW** *shell script* for production purposes.</sup>

---

*Example* **XML Plist** *code*:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>Label</key>
    <string>com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW</string>
    <key>ProgramArguments</key>
    <array>
        <string>/usr/local/bin/changeKSforMFTNW</string>
    </array>
    <key>RunAtLoad</key>
    <false/>
    <key>WatchPaths</key>
    <array>
        <string>/Users/you/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist</string>
    </array>
</dict>
</plist>
```

---

**Notes:**

- Be sure to change `you` in `<string>/Users/you/Library/Preferences/com.apple.HIToolbox.plist</string>` in the **XML Plist** file used for the **Launch Agent** to the *name* of you **Home** *folder*.
- Sans the *code* changes to target the correct `key code` and fully automating the solution, the conditions mentioned in the original answer, listed below, still apply as applicable.
- The *naming convention* for the *shell script* e.g. `changeKSforMFTNW` stands for, *change keyboard shortcut for move focus to next window* and applies to that portion of the **com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist** *file* too. Obviously for testing purposes I need to use something. However, change the *naming convention* as you desire.
- Some of the *shell commands* that are formatted as a *compound command* are done so because in a clean install of **macOS** the `bin` *directory* in `/usr/local` does not exist even though `/usr/local/bin` is in the `PATH` (and `path` in a *zsh shell*). As well as the `LaunchAgents` *directory* in `$HOME/Library`. (`mkdir -p` could be used in lieu of the `[ ... ] | &&` paradigm.)
- When using **Launch Agents** and **Launch Daemons**, I highly recommend reading the *manual pages* for `launchctl`, `launchd.plist` and `launchd`. You can read the *manual page* for *`command`* in **Terminal** by typing *`command`* and then right-click on it and select: **Open man Page**

**Reverting Changes**

To completely undo the changes made by this, in **Terminal**:

```
cd ~/Library/LaunchAgents
launchctl stop com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
launchctl unload com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
rm com.my.change.KS.for.MFTNW.plist
cd /usr/local/bin
sudo rm changeKSforMFTNW
```

In **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** uncheck and remove **osascript** if not being used otherwise.

In **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Automation** uncheck **System Events** under **osascript** if not being used otherwise.

---

**Original Answer**

<sup>**Note**: The original answer is beening kept as part of the overall answer as the *example* **AppleScript** *code* used as the *proof of concept* has value for someone else wanting this solution for different *keyboard input* other then the two languages beening used by the OP.</sup>

Whenever I have have to do something repetitiously I automate it in some manner so as to not have to manually take all the steps necessary to accomplish the task.

In this particular case, as much as I do not like to use **UI Scripting**, nonetheless, I'll do it when it is the easiest way I know, with all things considered.

Presented as a *proof of concept*, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* shown below was tested and worked for me without issues as is under **macOS Catalina** 10.15.7 in **Script Editor**, under the following conditions:

- **System Preferences** > **Language & Region**:

  - **Preferred languages:**
  - **English**
  - **English (US) — Primary**
- **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility**

  - **[√] Script Editor**
- **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Keyboard**

  - **[ ] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls**
  - **[√] Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls**
- Allowed the *script* to run uninterrupted and not taking focus away from **System Preferences**, as is necessary in this use case in order to use **UI Scripting** to set the *keyboard shortcut*.
- Changes may be needed to the *code* in general when run on other versions of **macOS** and or different **Language** settings, and was only tested under the aforementioned conditions and the condition expressed in the next paragraph.

I also tested the *example* **AppleScript** *code* saved as an **AppleScript** *application*, noting that the *application* needs to be added to **System Preferences** > **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and clicking the **OK** *button* on the, e.g., '“Toggle ⌘` - ⌘=“ wants access to control “System Events“. Allowing control will provide access to documents and data in “System Events“, and to perform actions within that app.' dialog box. (Obviously the name of the *application* will be whatever it was named. I used **Toggle ⌘` - ⌘=** for testing purposes.)

Although it was not tested in the following manner, nonetheless, the *example* **AppleScript** *code* should also be able to be used in a **Run AppleScript** *action* in an **Automator** *Service/Quick Action*, or a third-party automation type *application* that can make use of **AppleScript**.

The *example* **AppleScript** *code* toggles the *value* of the *keyboard shortcut* for: **System Preferences** > **Keyboard** > **Shortcuts** > **Keyboard** > **Move focus to next window**

For this *proof of concept* it toggles between **⌘`** and **⌘=**, and **⌘=** is not really meant to be used, it strictly a placeholder for whatever the `key code` *value* of **`º`** is, which you'll have to determine.

I determine the *value* of *key codes* using a free third-party utility named [**Key Codes**](https://manytricks.com/keycodes/), by [**Many Tricks**](https://manytricks.com), and is available for download from the developers web site, or the [**Mac AppStore**](https://apps.apple.com/us/app/key-codes/id414568915?mt=12). (I am not affiliated with the developer of **Key Codes**, just a satisfied user.)

I have also commented the *code* so you may have an understanding of what it's doing, and it is near the very bottom of the *code* where you need to change:

```
key code 24 using command down --   # {"⌘="}
```

To:

```
key code ? using command down --    # {"⌘º"}
```

Where `?` is the *value* for **Key Code:** in the **Key Codes** *application* when the **`º`** *key* is pressed.

Or possibly<sup>1</sup> use the `keystroke` *command*, e.g.:

```
keystroke "º" using command down -- # {"⌘º"}
```

<sup>1</sup> Without a **Spanish** *keyboard* I cannot effectively test the the `keystroke` *command*.

---

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
--  # Check to see if System Preferences is 
--  # running and if yes, then close it.
--  # 
--  # This is done so the script will not fail 
--  # if it is running and a modal sheet is 
--  # showing, hence the use of 'killall' 
--  # as 'quit' fails when done so, if it is.
--  #
--  # This is also done to allow default behaviors
--  # to be predictable from a clean occurrence.

if running of application "System Preferences" then
    try
        tell application "System Preferences" to quit
    on error
        do shell script "killall 'System Preferences'"
    end try
    delay 0.1
end if

--  # Make sure System Preferences is not running before
--  # opening it again. Otherwise there can be an issue
--  # when trying to reopen it while it is actually closing.

repeat while running of application "System Preferences" is true
    delay 0.1
end repeat

--  # Open System Preferences to the Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane.
--  # 
--  # This UI Script needs it to be visible, hence the activate command.

tell application "System Preferences"
    activate
    reveal anchor "shortcutsTab" of ¬
        pane id "com.apple.preference.keyboard"
end tell

--  # System Events does the navigating around the 
--  # Shortcuts tab of the Keyboard pane and changes
--  # the value of the target keyboard shortcut.

tell application "System Events"
    
    --  # Make sure the UI is ready to be navigated.
    
    repeat until (exists checkbox 1 of ¬
        tab group 1 of ¬
        window 1 of ¬
        process "System Preferences")
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    --  # Press the Tab key twice.
    
    repeat 2 times
        key code 48
        delay 0.1
    end repeat
    
    --  # Select 'Keyboard' from the list on the left.
    --  # This is wrapped in a try statement to get
    --  # past a bug in how the select command is 
    --  # interpreted and is silently eaten.
    
    try
        select (every row of ¬
            table 1 of ¬
            scroll area 1 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" whose ¬
            value of static text 1 = "Keyboard")
    end try
    
    --  # Select 'Move focus to next window' from the 
    --  # list on the right. This is wrapped in a try
    --  # statement to get past a bug in how the select  
    --  # command is interpreted and is silently eaten.
    
    try
        select (every row of ¬
            outline 1 of ¬
            scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" whose ¬
            value of static text 1 of ¬
            UI element 2 is "Move focus to next window")
    end try
    
    --  # By default, when System Preferences opens, focus is in
    --  # the Search text box, and depending on whether or not the
    --  # 'Use keyboard navigation to move focus between controls'
    --  # is checked, it makes a difference when 'UI Scripting' is
    --  # being used. Set a flag so as to handle the differences.
    
    set isChecked to ¬
        the value of ¬
            checkbox 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" as boolean
    
    --  # Based on the state of the target check box,
    --  # press the Tab key the necessary times to
    --  # navigate to and or open the text field for
    --  # input of the target keyboard shortcut.
    
    if isChecked then
        delay 0.1
        repeat 3 times
            key code 48 --  # Tab key.
            delay 0.1
        end repeat
    else
        key code 48 --  # Tab key.
        delay 0.01
    end if
    
    --  # Toggle the value of the target keyboard shortcut.
    
    if the value of ¬
        text field 1 of ¬
        UI element 2 of ¬
        (every row of ¬
            outline 1 of ¬
            scroll area 2 of ¬
            splitter group 1 of ¬
            tab group 1 of ¬
            window 1 of ¬
            process "System Preferences" whose ¬
            value of ¬
            static text 1 of ¬
            UI element 2 ¬
                is "Move focus to next window") ¬
            is {"⌘`"} then
        
        key code 24 using command down --   # ⌘= keys
    else
        key code 50 using command down --   # ⌘` keys
    end if
    
    delay 0.5
    
end tell

tell application "System Preferences" to quit
```

<sup>Because of the comments and coding style the *script* is very long. It ends with `tell application "System Preferences" to quit`, so make sure you highlight all of it when copying and pasting to **Script Editor** for testing.</sup>

---

<sub>Note: The *example* **AppleScript** *code* is just that and sans any included *error handling* does not contain any additional  *error handling* as may be appropriate. The onus is upon the user to add any *error handling* as may be appropriate, needed or wanted. Have a look at the [**try**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129232) *statement* and [**error**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_control_statements.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH6g-129657) *statement* in the [**AppleScript Language Guide**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/introduction/ASLR_intro.html). See also, [**Working with Errors**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_xmpls.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH221-SW1). Additionally, the use of the [**delay**](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_cmds.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40000983-CH216-SW10) *command* may be necessary between events where appropriate, e.g. `delay 0.5`, with the *value* of the *delay* set appropriately.</sub>

Comment: Hey, thanks a lot. It worked, but I found the actual key code depends on the current input source, so I have to first check this, which I found here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21597804/determine-os-x-keyboard-layout-input-source-in-the-terminal-a-script

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, What I posted thus far was more of a _proof of concept_ if you know what the `key code` is for `º` when the Spanish keyboard is selected I have all the rest necessary to make the whole thing work automatically for you.  I just didn't want to post everything until you told tell me the `key code` for  `º` when the Spanish keyboard is selected . Just let me know what you want to do.

Comment: The keycode for º is 10 when using Spanish - ISO input source.

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, What version of **macOS** are you running, so I can test under the same **OS**?

Comment: version: 11.2.2

Comment: Hey, I have added the script to the Automator to activate it via a shortcut, but then I noticed that Macos will run the script as if it was started by the app that had focus by the time I type the shortcut, so I would have to add permission for all apps I use, which does not seem to be desirable. Is there a way to around this?

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, Okay, I've been coding and testing under **macOS Catalina**, I'll setup a **macOS Big Sur** 11.2.2 virtual machine and do my testing under it. Will update the answer after testing. -- RE: "Is there a way to around this?" Do not use **Automator**, and what I'm working on will only require permissions once on the initial setup. Will update my answer in a while.

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, I have updated my answer to provide a fully automated **UI Scripting** solution.  Please take the time to read it throughly before implementing it. If you have any question don't hesitate to ask.

Comment: @user3439894 This is an epic answer, and stuff like this is why I love this site. Thank you for sharing your time and expertise.

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, It would be nice to know if my updated answer provided you with a working solution. Also, if it did work for you and you feel so inclined to upvote and or mark it as the accepted answer, that would be appreciated too. Thanks.

Comment: Hey, today I finally had some time to go through this. I'm not sure what happened, but it looks like it entered in a loop where it was trying to change the shortcut all the time. Later I'll review to see if I have missed anything. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, In the **Create the Launch Agent:** section... Open **System Preferences** to **Security & Privacy** > **Privacy** > **Accessibility** and click the **Lock**, enter your (Admin) credentials and then drag and drop `osascript` onto the list on the right side of **Accessibility** and ensure it is checked. You can then close **System Preferences**. **NOTE:** Make sure you do this before loading the **Launch Agent**. --- If you do not do this before loading the **Launch Agent** that is probably why it went into a loop.

Comment: Found what was the problem. Instead of "com.apple.keylayout.US" I'm using "com.apple.keylayout.ABC". After this change it is working fine now. Thanks.

Comment: I have also added scripts at /Users/my-user/Library/Services to link the "wrong key" to the action of switching the input source, so when I type ⌘` while input source is Spanish it will be considered ⌘< and it triggers the switch automatically. When input source is ABC and I type ⌘º it will be considered ⌘§ and switches the input source.

Comment: Hey, just found another thing: the script is not immediately triggered when the input source is changed. It is only triggered in the first key stroke after the change. So I'm pressing shift after the change to get it fired.

Comment: @Constantino Cronemberger, I didn't experience that issue, however, I'll take a look and see if I can replicate the issue, then see what can be automated to resolve it programmatically so you do not have to manually press the shift key.